# How to clear the value from input text in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a custom lightning component that creates a new Task record. I use Ui:inputtext for Description standard field in Task .

I want to clear it's values if the user clicks save.

`<ui:inputTextArea aura:id="taskSubject" label="Comments" value="{!v.newTask.Description}"/>

            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:5rem">  <ui:button label="Create Task" press="{!c.createNewTask}"/></div>`

Controller :

```
createNewTask : function(component, event, helper) {
var action = component.get("c.saveTask");
var newTask = component.get("v.newTask");
action.setParams({
    "task": newTask
    });
action.setCallback(this,function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
    if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
        var items = component.get("v.tasks");
        items.push(response.getReturnValue());

       component.set("v.tasks",items);
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    }
    else{
        console.log("Failed with state "+state);
    }
});
```

Comment: component.set("v.newTask.Description",''); 
use this line in method you are calling in save button.

Comment: add at last after your apex call finish. so that it will make it blank after your save functionality done

Comment: Thanks patelkiran ,now its clearing the value from description field 
my issue is the data  was getting saved but from UI it was not getting cleared

Comment: can u post your `Init` Function. you have to bind empty value when u component first initialization.

Comment: it worked for me, i was putting wrong place
thanks @patelkiran

Answer (score 0):

```
component.set("v.newTask.Description",'');
```

use this line, add at last after your apex call finish. so that it will make it blank after your save functionality done.